# A break in the 5-7-5-7-7 meter?

Tags: meter, japanese-language

So I was reading about Waka poetry and then about the tanka meter, when I came across several poems by Ono no Komachi and Narihira. The ついにゆく poem from Narihira has 8 syllables rather than 7 in the last line and the first line in Komachi’s 花の色は has 6 syllables rather than the standard 5 right?

I was wondering if this was allowed or is there a special rule where some sounds were combined or maybe I’m supposed to turn a blind eye and the meter is more of a ‘guideline’ rather than actual rules.

Comment: I am not an expert in Japanese language or literature, but it appears this website agrees with your syllable count http://www.kangin.or.jp/learning/text/poetry/s_D1_30.html

Comment: My other speculation is that as there are some historic alternative pronunciations of 花, one of those would fix the meter. https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E8%8A%B1#Japanese

Comment: @AdamBurke: In other words, this is Shakespeares's "stretchèd meter of an antique song."